# How to create a batch file from shell script

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file, server

I have a script to run on a unix box that looks for the most recently-added file in a directory and writes the name of that file to a new file. It looks like

```
ls -t|head -n 1 >> ../latestfile.txt
```

However I now need to get this to run on a windows box and have been told it needs to be .bat.  Can anyone help with what this would look like?

Comment: That is not a script, it is a single command. I suggest you take a look at the documentation of the shell environment you want to use on the MS-Windows platform. That should show you what commands are available there and what options are recognized.

Comment: The answer of @foxidrive seems best when you can not develop on the system. PowerShell is a more complex solution, nice when you have to do a lot of scipting in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and call it a day.

> > Cygwin is a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Afterwards you should the be able to run that command from the regular Windows command line, a Batch File, or a Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 1):

This effectively gives the same result.

```
@echo off
 :latest file
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /od /a-d') do >"latestfile.txt" echo %%a
```

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive. I don't have access to the environment so I can't test.  It's a third party company that we work with but I'll pass this on to them. Thanks again!

Comment: You should use `>>` instead of `>`, and you need a `GOTO` abort the loop after the first (newest) entry is listed.

Comment: @dbenham I was sneakily emulating his code in one line Dave - it does indeed end up with only the latest filename in the file. It's fine for a small bunch of files but if there are 4.4 million files in the folder then it will take a little longer than usual. :)

Comment: Doh - it took a while, but I finally see how it works. Yes, it is sneaky. Kind of like setting the same variable in a loop - the last one wins.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent for `ls -t` in Windows `cmd` could be:

- `dir /B /TC /OD /A-D` - sorted (see `/OD`) by creation date & time (see `/TC`);
- `dir /B /TW /OD /A-D` - sorted (see `/OD`) by last write date & time (see `/TW`): the same if `/T` switch omitted at all.

`head -n 1` equivalent: to get the most recent file name (add `/TC` switch if desired), i.e. last item in `dir /b` output to a variable:

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /B /OD /A-D') do set "_lastfile=%~G"
```

Next `.bat` should work (note doubled `%` in the loop variable name `%%G`) and add a line containing *filename (incl. extension if present, no path) of the recently changed file from current directory* to the  `..\latestfile.txt`. Here the `..\` means *parent folder* of the current directory.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "_lastfile="                 empty the `_lastfile` variable
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /OD /A-D') do set "_lastfile=%%~G"
>> ..\latestfile.txt echo(%_lastfile%
```

To add fully qualified file name, change the last line as follows:

```
>> ..\latestfile.txt echo(%CD%\%_lastfile%
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>>`, `>` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: thanks for this and the resources.  I'll get these checked out on Monday as I don't actually have access to the environment.